# Swift: Save selected multiply rows to firebase?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to Swift and I'm making my first application, so the question will be asked will be in a simpler way, not exactly with programming terms.
I have a table with names, which are also written in the Firebase. I need the ones I will select, and I press the save button, to write them (selected rows with names) in the database as a new child.

And my code is:

```
let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var ref: DatabaseReference!
var guestList = [GuestModel]()
var indexArray: [Int] = []

func addTable(){
    ref = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("tables")
    let key = ref.childByAutoId().key
    
    let table = ["id": key, "tableName": entertableNameTextField.text! as String, "tableCapacity": tableCapacityTextField.text! as String, "tableNo": enterTableNumber.text! as String, "guestsOnTable" : "\(indexArray)" as String]
    ref.child(key!).setValue(table)
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return guestList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "guestListCell", for: indexPath) as! GuestListToTableTableViewCell
    let guest: GuestModel
    guest = guestList[indexPath.row]
    cell.fullNameLabel.text = guest.guestName! + " " + guest.guestFamilyName!
    return cell
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    indexArray.append(indexPath.row)
    
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can take a key(in Firbase) and set is default false while click on it set it true.

and your logic will be.

in didselect method

> you need to update that key to true.

```
tblView.reloadData()
```

in cellforRow method

> check selected true change your cell design as well you want.